# How do I view NSLog on Xcode 11 iOS 13?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode11, unnotificationserviceextension

In Objective-C, I want to print and view a variable value in NotificationServiceExtension's `didReceiveNotificationRequest` method. How do I print and where can I see the log?

I tried the following and checked Xcode console. I'm unable to find the log which I printed.

```
NSLog(@"NotificationService %@", badgeCount);
```

I am using Xcode 11 and a real device with iOS version 13.

Comment: Are you debugging the main app instead of the NSE process?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140158/debug-notification-extensions