Why is the image not appearing in iOS push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging?
I’m implementing push notifications with an image in my iOS app using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). I've created a custom NotificationServiceExtension to handle the image download and attachment. However, the image is not showing in the notification.
Here is the code I’m using:
NotificationService.swift::
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    private var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    private var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)defer {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent ?? request.content)
        }
guard let attachment = request.attachment else {
            return
        }
bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
    }
override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}

extension UNNotificationRequest {
    var attachment: UNNotificationAttachment? {
        guard let attachmentURL = content.userInfo["image"] as? String,
              let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: attachmentURL)!) else {
            return nil
        }
        return try? UNNotificationAttachment(data: imageData, options: nil)
    }
}

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    convenience init(data: Data, options: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) throws {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let temporaryFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let temporaryFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .appendingPathComponent(temporaryFolderName, isDirectory: true)
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: temporaryFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        
        let imageFileIdentifier = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
        let fileURL = temporaryFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        try self.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
    }
}

FCM Payload
Here’s the payload I’m sending from the server:
message = messaging.Message(
    data=convert_to_firebase_compatible(data),
    token=registration_id,
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        priority='high',
        ttl=ttl
    ),
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=data.get('title', 'ABC'),
        body=data.get('message', ''),
        image=data.get('image_url', '')
    ),
    apns=messaging.APNSConfig(
        headers={
            'apns-priority': '10',
        },
        payload=messaging.APNSPayload(
            aps=messaging.Aps(
                sound='default',
                mutable_content='1'
            ),
        ),
        fcm_options=messaging.APNSFCMOptions(
            image=data.get('image_url', '')
        )
    ),
)

Issue:

The notifications are being received on iOS, but the image is not displayed.
I confirmed that the image URL in the userInfo payload is valid and accessible.

Steps Taken:

Added a NotificationServiceExtension to handle image attachment.
Verified the image_url in the payload is correct and accessible.
Confirmed the mutable_content is set to "1" in the payload.

Questions:

Am I missing any steps in setting up the NotificationServiceExtension to handle images?
Is the FCM payload correctly structured for sending images in iOS notifications?
Do I need to configure anything else for APNs or FCM to support images in notifications?


What is the attachment's size? It should, in my opinion, be displayed in a really light way until the service extension timeout occurs. And can you provide the raw payload that you received from FCM?

193KB, jPEG image, How to get row payload?

You can print out it in userNotificationCenter(_didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) in AppDelegate.

Did you set a breakpoint in your extension and step through to see what it is doing?

im new to develop ios flutter, I donn't know how to add breakpoint and debug it.

Check This :: -- https://medium.com/@akhil-ge0rge/implementing-image-push-notifications-in-flutter-with-firebase-for-ios-android-aaa1cc1120eb
try with a image size below 300kb

To set a breakpoint you will need to open your project in Xcode and set a breakpoint in your extension code at the relevant line. You can then use the debug menu to attach to a process by name (which will be the bundle id of your extension) and then send a push notification. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140158/debug-notification-extensions

breakpoints added  but its not stopping there.
